# EF code first - getting DynamicProxies instead of objects. Why?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a following query:

```
using (var forumsDb = new ForumsDb())
{
   forumsDb.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   var categoryList = forumsDb.Categories.Select(c => c).ToList();
   /***some code here***/
}
```

Now, `categoryList` contains 4 items (i have 4 categories in database), but all of them are of type `dynamicproxies`, and not (as i would expect) `Category`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are the reference(s) marked as virtual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  EF wraps your entities in a version tracking proxy so that it can detect changes to your objects as well as support Lazy Loading.

If you want to remove the proxies, you can detach the object from the context, or you can turn off version tracking altogether by specifying `DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` false

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic proxies are automatically created wrappers around your objects that handles change tracking to make sure correct objects are saved when you run SaveChanges.

The inherit from your objects (in your case `Category`) and can be used as the corresponding object.